# Read from text file and make a dictionary text file

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to read a text file and store new words in linked list. From this linked list I want to write a dictionary file with new words. I don't know why my code don't run. Can anyone help me?

p/s: when i run debug it found this when store vector element to new_node->word
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXSGz.png)
This is my code

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
typedef struct dictionary
{   string word;
    int line;
    int page;
    struct dictionary* next;
} node;


int main()
{
    node* Head = NULL;
    ifstream file("filetest.txt");
    if(file.fail())
        cout << "Loi mo file! "<<endl;
    string temp;
    int cpage = 1,cline = 1;
    while(getline(file,temp))
    {
        stringstream spliter;
        spliter << temp;
        vector<string> result;
        while(!spliter.eof())
        {
            string str;
            spliter >> str;
            result.push_back(str);
        }
        for(size_t i = 0;i != result.size();i++)
        {
            if(Find(Head,result[i])==0)
            {
                Append(&Head,result[i],cline,cpage);
            }

        }
        cline++;
        if(cline == 25)
            cpage++;

    }
    file.close();
    ;
    ofstream outfile("test.txt");
    node* p = Head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        outfile << p->word <<","<<p->page<<"-"<<p->line<<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }


}
```

Append( add member to linked list)

```
void Append(node** First,string &newstr,int newl,int newp)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* last = *First;
    new_node->word=newstr;
    new_node->line=newl;
    new_node->page=newp;
    new_node->next = 0;
    if(*First == 0)
    {
        *First = new_node;
        return;
    }
    while(last->next != 0)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}
```

Find( check if a word is new or not)

```
int Find(node* head,string &tumoi)
{
    node* current = head;
    while(current != 0)
    {
        if(current->word == tumoi)
            return 1;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***I don't know why my code don't run*** That is what a debugger is for. I recommend you use Visual Studio if possible. Then single step through your input loop looking at your program flow and variables.

Comment: Keep an eye on `while(!spliter.eof())` [It is almost always the wrong way to loop IO reads.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: What are `Find` and `Append`? What is a `node`? `cline` I'm familiar with. He wrote Buckaroo Banzai Against the World Crime League.

Comment: I use Codeblocks and when i run debug it stop when store vector<string> element which i read from file text to a member of struct. It shows like the first image that i post @drescherjm

Comment: Doesn't Code::Blocks have a version of gdb integrated? If it does don't just run your code in the debugger. Step through the code a line at a time.

Comment: @user4581301 i post it in image because my code is too long. Sorry for my bad english. cline is line of word which i want to store.

Comment: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: It said "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." @drescherjm

Comment: On what line did it do that when you stepped through your code line by line?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you for your help @drescherjm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `malloc` with C++ types. It does not properly initialize them.

Your `node` struct contains a `std::string` which needs to have its constructor called to be properly initialized.

When you do this

```
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->word=newstr;
```

The `new_node->word` is not initialized and can contain pointers to nowhere.

You should do

```
    node* new_node = new node();
    new_node->word=newstr;
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure to use `delete` instead of `free` on your nodes.

Comment: ***What can i do to fix it?*** No idea. Time to go back to using your debugger. Also that is a different totally separate problem than this question which is answered.

Comment: Micronag: They are pointers to somewhere, but that somewhere is definitely a bad place to point.